# for all objects, rename 'Vertex Colors" that has a certain name :: using python

Tags: python, vertex-colors

Many objects in my scene has Vertex color ***(left image)*** that is used in Shader Node ***(right image)***.

[image]
[image]

^ I want to change `color1` to a more meaningful name e.g. `color2` (for the sake of example).

However, renaming it in Shader Node ***(right image)*** alone is not enough - I need to rename vertex color for each object too ***(left image)***.

How to rename/update-the-name of vertex color name `color1` of **every** object in file to `color2`?

After I searched, I believe there is no such feature.  Can it be done using python?

```
# 1. get all object (how?)
# 2. check whether each object has vertex color name `color1`
# 3.  ... if so, get integer index of the slot, and rename the slot to `color2`
       perhap it may look like this code :-
bpy.data.objects[some_object_name_string].renameVertexColor(`color1`,`color2`)  ???
```

Comment: @brockmann :: sorry for not being clear,  I want only "How to change the name of the vertex color group".  I can do the later (shader node) by hand.  ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
import bpy

name_before = "color1"
name_after = "color2"

for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    col_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.get(name_before)
    if col_layer is not None:
        col_layer.name = name_after

        # Make sure it renamed; it won't work if there
        # was already another layer named color2
        assert col_layer.name == name_after
```

If you want to update materials (and node groups) too, add this

```
node_trees = [mat.node_tree for mat in bpy.data.materials]
node_trees += list(bpy.data.node_groups)

for node_tree in node_trees:
    if node_tree:
        for node in node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'VERTEX_COLOR':
                if node.layer_name == name_before:
                    node.layer_name = name_after
            elif node.type == 'ATTRIBUTE':
                if node.attribute_name == name_before:
                    node.attribute_name = name_after
```

Comment: I tested the first half, it works.  Thank a lot!

Comment: The second half works mostly.  However, it has no effect for Vertex Color Node inside Node Group.

Comment: Hah, I thought about doing groups too. I'll update it.

Comment: Now, it works for nodes in node group too. Thank!

Comment: How did you come with such a fast and correct answer?  Did you search some reference? or ... are you a professional that just remember most useful Blender python commands?

Comment: lol. I've contributed a little to some addons so I remember the general shape of the API. Python tooltips and autocomplete in the Python Console work to fill in the details. The API refs are [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/) if you want to look through them though.